# Android Studio 4.0 does not highlight and color native C++ code syntax

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, native

Since Android Studio 4.0 update I am not able to see colored, syntax-highlighted native C++ code.

This also makes not possible to set a breakpoint in C++ code.

`externalNativeBuild` does get launched, CMake builds the code.

Also no code navigation.

When I have downgraded to Android 3.6.1 the whole Android native code support works fine.

How to fix this?

[image: Example for cpp file]

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on Android Studio. The code does build correctly but when looking the code in the newer (4.1.1) Android Studio says the code doesn't belong to the project. It still works in the previous 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, turns out I had to tell android studio that my project had c++ code in it.

In my case there was a option in the file menu (android studio for Mac version Artic Fox 2020.3.1) saying "add c++ to project" (or something like that, I can't get it back now).

When clicking that it asked me if I wanted to create a new `CMakeList.txt` file or if I had one already. Since I had one already I chose the latter, chose my `CMakeList.txt` and everything synched up correctly.